# Spivak's proof of the chain rule in $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Spivak's proof of the chain rule in $\mathbb{R^n}$.  The proof can be found on  page 19.

I'm confused by the last step.  "Equation 6 now follows easily."

[Page 19](http://www.scribd.com/doc/34158129/Calculus-on-manifolds-Spivak-M-pdf#page=31)

Comment: Could you kindly add the proof or give a link where the proof can be found?

Comment: Spivak has more than one book...

Comment: Sorry, I just added the link.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that I took   [this proof](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HpqWjOcrUc&list=PLEA04DA0876A339C1&index=8&feature=plpp_video)  from Spivak. You might find it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Divide across by $|x-a|$ giving $\frac{|\psi(f(x))|}{|x-a|} \leq \epsilon \frac{|\phi(x)|}{|x-a|}+\epsilon M$. Line (4) shows that the $\frac{|\phi(x)|}{|x-a|} \to 0$, hence bounded, so this shows that $\frac{|\psi(f(x))|}{|x-a|} \to 0$, since $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary.

Comment: Is it certain that $\lim_{x\ \to a}\frac{|\psi(f(x))|}{|x-a|} $ exists?

Comment: Yes, the above shows that the limit is $0$. That is, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta > 0$, such that when $|x-a| < \delta$, then $\frac{|\psi(f(x))|}{|x-a|} < \epsilon$.